# Converting from Java Timestamp to Oracle Timestamp

Tags: java, oracle

In my java project I'm trying to create a timestamp that will be stored later in the database (Oracle Database).
After many trials I found that the timestamp my java code generates is in the following format:

```
2017-06-20 14:38:12.296
```

and the timestamp format in Oracle is like:

```
20-JUN-19 02.38.55.059000000 PM
```

Is there a way to convert the java format of timestamp to oracle's format?

My code for creating the timestamp:

```
Date date = new Date();
long time = date.getTime();
Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(time);
```

I have tried so many timestamps conversions but with no use.

Comment: The format of timestamp is irrelevant (in both Oracle and Java). Please show us the full classname of the Timestamp from your example and also tell us how would youlike to write the timestamp into database.

Comment: This is the java class for the timestamp: java.sql.Timestamp, and I would like to convert the first format above to this format "20-JUN-19 02.38.55.059000000 PM" ,as an example, in order to insert it into the database.

Comment: That is the correct type. You do not need to reformat it in order to put in into Oracle. Just write into database (e.g., via JDBC) and you will see Oracle shows it in the correct format.

Comment: You need to understand - the formats you are showing are not relevant when storing the timestamp in database. The timestamp is just a number and that number is all what is needed to store it in database.

Comment: Another way to tell you what Michal is saying, is that the timestamp is always the same value no matter what format you give it, the format only matters for visual purpose to show to the user.

Comment: Of course, I suppose the Oracle column is TIMESTAMP or similar, e.g. not VARCHAR.

Answer (score 2):

To add from QuaternionsRock's answer, since it's not tested, you can always use [DateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html).

From his link, you can see the following example, which I am able to test with a date such as 20-JUN-19 06.06.05.112 PM.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss.SSS a");
Date date = df.parse(oracleTS);
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

There does not need to be two `a` in the DateFormat string, contrary to what is posted in QuaternionsRock' link.

Answer (score -1):

From [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2103059):

```
java.sql.Timestamp javaTimeStamp = oracleTimeStamp.timestampValue();
```

I can't say I've tested it but it seems logical to me.

Comment: This is how to convert from an oracle timeStamp to a java timeStamp; OP requested the inverse.